# How do Wayland clients communicate with the server?

Tags: x11, wayland

I know that the X window system protocol was based over a network, and this is how clients communicate with the X server. Now Wayland seeks to remove this network reliance.

My question is, how are Wayland clients supposed to communicate with the compositor? What is the medium for the protocol messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://wayland.freedesktop.org/docs/html/ch04.html#sect-Protocol-Wire-Format

> The protocol is sent over a UNIX domain stream socket